# why does Scikit Learn's Power Transform always transform the data to zero standard deviation?

Tags: scikit-learn, normalization

all of my input features are positive. Whenever I tried to apply PowerTransformer with box-cox method, the lambdas are s.t. the transformed values have zero variance. i.e. the features become constants

I even tried with randomly generated log normal data and it still transform the data into zero variance.

I do understand that mathematically, finding the lambda s.t. the standard deviation is the smallest, would mean the distribution would be the most normal-like.

But when the standard deviation is zero, then what's the point of using it?

p.s. so one of the values of lambda I get by using PowerTranformer is -4.78

If you apply it into the box-cox equation for lambda != 0.0, then for any input feature y values, you technically get the same values. i.e. (100^(-4.78)-1.0)/(-4.78) is technically equals to (500^(-4.78)-1.0)/(-4.78)

Comment: Can you add a sample of your code? That way we can see what input you use and whether you use specific parameters in the function

Comment: I would need more information but maybe check the following two things: 1) you said "positive" but box-cox requires "strictly positive" values. Are any of your values zeros? 2) the default for the power transformer is to standardize your data, make sure that you understand what this means for your problem